# New menu item doesn't appear in UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate's Module Zero.

I added a new menu item in `SetNavigation` method in the `ProjectNameNavigationProvider` class in the `Mpa` project after the `Role` menu item, but it doesn't appear in the Admin Dashboard.

I set the `text`/`value` in the `Localization` folder in the `.Core` project for the menu item too, but the problem isn't resolved.

the `ProjectNameNavigationProvider` Class and `SetNavigation` Method

```
public override void SetNavigation(INavigationProviderContext context)
            {
                context.Manager.MainMenu
                    .AddItem(
                        new MenuItemDefinition(
                            PageNames.Home,
                            L("HomePage"),
                            url: "",
                            icon: "home",
                            requiresAuthentication: true
                        )
                    ).AddItem(
                        new MenuItemDefinition(
                            PageNames.Tenants,
                            L("Tenants"),
                            url: "Tenants",
                            icon: "business",
                            requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants
                        )
                    ).AddItem(
                        new MenuItemDefinition(
                            PageNames.Users,
                            L("Users"),
                            url: "Users",
                            icon: "people",
                            requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Users
                        )
                    ).AddItem(
                        new MenuItemDefinition(
                            PageNames.Roles,
                            L("Roles"),
                            url: "Roles",
                            icon: "local_offer",
                            requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Roles
                        )
                    )
                    .AddItem(
                        new MenuItemDefinition(
                            PageNames.News,
                            L("News"),
                            url: "News",
                            icon: "fa-newspaper-o",
                            requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_News
                        )
                    )
                    .AddItem(
                        new MenuItemDefinition(
                            PageNames.About,
                            L("About"),
                            url: "About",
                            icon: "info"
                        )
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you set the `requiredPermissionName` of the menu item as `PermissionNames.Pages_News`, you need to assign that permission for the user to see that menu item in the UI.

You can assign the permission to a `Role` that the user has, or directly to the user.

Comment: thank you for replying but when i assign the news permission to a admin role the checkbox is disable and doesn't change when i click it.

Comment: yes.  i define new rule Temporary and assign new permission to it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the multi tenancy side of the permission. A permission can be assigned to tenant owners or tenants. Check whether you have set this flag or not. This is important.

**MultiTenancySides**: For multi-tenant application, a permission can be used by tenants or the host. This is a Flags enumeration and thus a permission can be used in both sides.

Related docs: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Authorization
Example usage:

```
context.CreateChildPermission(PermissionNames.Pages_News, L("News"), multiTenancySides: MultiTenancySides.Tenant);
```